# WebView2 control not return Bing AI tool (COPILOT) output in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, bing, webview2

I want to save the output of the Bing AI tool (COPILOT) through the `WebView2` control in a Windows application (C#).

[image]

But the part of the HTML form that is related to this section is not included in the output of the following command:

```
webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: That text is not part of the root Document's text. As you can see, the HTML structure contains nested Shadow DOMs (document fragments), which implies Web Components are in use here. You need to go deeper (the `.shadowRoot` of an Element references the inner document fragment)